# Looking for ForeignKey active and add to QuerySet

Tags: python, django, annotate

```
class Control(models.Model):
    period = models.DurationField()
    active = models.BooleanField()
    device_collection = models.ForeignKey(DeviceSet)

class DeviceSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    date_last_control = models.DateField()

    def get_next_control(self):
        return self.date_last_control + self.control_actif.period

    @property
    def control_actif(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_control"):
            setattr(self, "_control", self.control_set.get(active=True))
        return self._control
```

There are several Control associated with DeviceSet but only one Control which is active by DeviceSet.
I'd like to get the active Control of the DeviceSet when I get the queryset in a column _control.
I already try :

```
DeviceSet.objects.annotate(_control = Q(control__active=True))
```

That don't work

```
'WhereNode' object has no attribute 'output_field'
```

And after set output_field=Control I have the following exception:

```
type object 'Control' has no attribute 'resolve_expression'
```

I just want to have like a prefetch_related with filter but in a new column to use the _control attribute in model's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting errors from what you've attempted because `annotate` method needs an aggregate function (eg `Sum`, `Count` etc) rather than a `Q` object.

Since Django 1.7 it's possible to do what you want using `prefetch_related`, see docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch

```
DeviceSet.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('control_set',
             queryset=Control.objects.filter(active=True),
             to_attr='_control')
)
```